# Shell Process substitution and xargs Command doesn't work

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I am using the Process substitution to pipe the awk results to grep and sed

```
grep "." | sed 's|.*\:||' \
 <(awk '{arr[$5"\t"$6]++}END{for (a in arr) {if(arr[a]>2){print a, arr[a]}}}' file1) \
 <(awk '{arr[$5"\t"$6]++}END{for (a in arr) {if(arr[a]>2){print a, arr[a]}}}' file2) | 
 awk '{cnt[$0]++} END{for (rec in cnt) if (cnt[rec] == 1) print rec}' | 
 awk ' {print $1}'
```

However, piping each result to xargs doesn't seem to work

```
grep "." | sed 's|.*\:||' | xargs -I {} grep -E {} ${probeFileLog} ${ObjectServerLog} <(awk  '{arr[$5"\t"$6]++}END{for (a in arr) {if(arr[a]>2){print a, arr[a]}}}' file1) <(awk  '{arr[$5"\t"$6]++}END{for (a in arr) {if(arr[a]>2){print a, arr[a]}}}' file2) | awk '{cnt[$0]++} END{for (rec in cnt) if (cnt[rec] == 1) print rec}' | xargs -I {} grep -E {} ${probeFileLog} ${ObjectServerLog}
```

sed outputs the following

```
749963941   3 4
749963940   3 3
749963939   3 3
749963937   3 3
749963935   3 3
749963933   3 3
749963941   3 4
749963938   3 3
749963936   3 3
749963934   3 3
749963932   3 3
```

Comment: What part of your sed's output is needed as an argument to grep? How should grep's form look like? I mean an example expanded form.

Comment: The `grep "." |` part of the opening command is completely irrelevant because the `sed` command reads from the files created by the process substitution, not from standard input.

Comment: Having split the monster line into 5 vastly improves the legibility.  I think, though, you should be able to do better than 4 `awk` commands to produce the output.  It would be interesting to see a few lines of input; it isn't obvious what the `sed` is doing because we've not seen the input data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first line (which would be easier to read with new lines), you have:

```
grep "." | sed 's|.*\:||' <( awk ... )
```

which is effectively equivalent to something like this:

```
grep "." | sed 's|.*\:||' /dev/fd/63
```

(where `/dev/fd/63` is a pipe.)

That means that `sed` reads from `/dev/fd/63` rather than `stdin`, so it ignores any output from `grep`. Meanwhile, `grep` is waiting from input from the console. I would have thought that you would have  noticed that, because you'll have to interrupt the command after it finishes.

I think that what you meant was to send the `awk` output to `grep`:

```
grep "." <( awk ...) | sed 's|.*\:||'
```

And if you do that, it will work with `xargs`::

```
grep "." <( awk ...) | sed 's|.*\:||' | xargs ...
```

By the way, `grep "."` will match any non-empty line. I'm not sure if that is what you intended or not.

Comment: yes ricci it waits for the Input.. grep "."   <(awk  '{arr[$5"\t"$6]++}END{for (a in arr) {if(arr[a]>1){print a, arr[a]}}}' ${probeFileLog}) <(awk  '{arr[$5"\t"$6]++}END{for (a in arr) {if(arr[a]>1){print a, arr[a]}}}' ${ObjectServerLog})  | sed 's|.*:||' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs  -I {} grep -E {} ${probeFileLog} ${ObjectServerLog} works :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean to pass only 1 argument at a time. Use `-n 1`:

```
... xargs -n 1 -I {} grep -E {} ...
```

If your patterns are separated by newlines not spaces, specify it explicitly as well:

```
... xargs -n 1 -d '\n' -I {} grep -E {} ...
```

Also consider quoting your variables to prevent word splitting:

```
... "${probeFileLog}" "${ObjectServerLog" ...
```